# PHP/Javascript - Show more function for an HTML page generated by tinyMCE

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, tinymce

I am using tinyMCE, a text editor to allow users to create blogs.  This can include text, images, breaks, etc anywhere on the page.  The output has HTML tags.

I am looking for a way to initially show a portion of the page along with a "show more" button at the end to click on, which in turn will show the rest of the page contents.

I know how to create a javascript show/hide function for text content, but my problem is how to find where this break should be for the first portion (initial showing), and for the second portion (rest of the content), since I can only break it at a point where the HTML must be valid.

Or is there a way to allow the entire content, but just visually hide a percentage of the content through some type of CSS?

Some initial direction would be appreciated!

EDIT:  I would consider using the "strtok" php command to get the first paragraph and just display that, however, it does not seem to work.  As an example:

```
$mystring = <<<EOF
<div>
<h2>Why do we use it?</h2>
<p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be 
    distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. 
    The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal 
    distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', 
    making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and 
   web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search 
   for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. 
   Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, 
   sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).<img style="float: 
   left; margin: 10px;" title="DSC00286.JPG" src="images/images91/imageID1527306461424.jpg" 
   alt="" width="200" height="154" /></p><p>test test test</p>
</div>
<div>
<h2>Where does it come from?</h2>
EOF;

$partialString = strtok($mystring, '</p>');
echo $partialString; 

THE RESULT IS: div
```

Probably missing something simple if someone can point it out?

Comment: You could just use css box height with overflow hidden and not have to mess with breaking apart the html. Then on your show more button just take overflow off the css to it auto expands to full height.

Answer (score 1):

place your content inside div

Html:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-8iPTk2s/jMVj81dnzb/iFR2sdA7u06vHJyyLlAd4snFpCl/SnyUjRrbdJsw1pGIl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="blog more" style="display:none;">
            <h1>First<h1>
        </div>
        <div class="blog more" style="display:none;">
            <h1>Second<h1>
        </div>
        <div class="blog more" style="display:none;">
            <h1>Third<h1>
        </div>
        <div class="blog more" style="display:none;">
            <h1>Fourth<h1>
        </div>
        <div class="blog more" style="display:none;">
            <h1>Fifth<h1>
        </div>

        <center><div class="" id="loadMore" style="display:inline-block;">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" style=" background-color:green; padding:4px 20px;" role="button"> Load More </a>
        </div></center>


     <script>
         $( document ).ready(function () {
            $(".more").slice(0, 2).show();
                if ($(".blog:hidden").length != 0) {
            $("#loadMore").show();
            }       
            $("#loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(".more:hidden").slice(0, 2).slideDown();
            if ($(".more:hidden").length == 0) {
                $("#loadMore").fadeOut('slow');
            }
        });
     });
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

change slice in js to show how many div you want to show or hide.

Answer (score 1):

The way I ended up using was as follows:

```
$minLength = 300;
$partialArticle = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+>/", "", $fullArticle,1);
$breakPosition = strpos($partialArticle,"</p>",$minLength);
$partialArticle = substr($partialArticle, 0, $breakPosition+4);
```

First define a typical length to display as the initial partial portion of the article.  I chose 300 characters.  Next, I decided to remove the image source so that the article displays will all look similar and only display 4 or 5 lines of writing.  Next, from the minimum length of 300, search for the end of the next paragraph so you will get a completed html structure for proper display.  Use the substr command to extract the portion to this end point.

Answer (score 0):

create 2 divs. one with the id initialShow and one with the id hidden. when the page loads have the div with the id initialShow  set to have a display: block;(which can be made in css). while the one with hidden can have a display: none;. then, when they click the button call a function to set the style of the div with the id hidden to display: block;

Comment: Good idea, but... these blog files are created by users who use tinyMCE as a text editor and they will not be getting into the html and inserting special id's.  Content is random and only basic html is output.  My need is to find a simple method to process this file and create one or more logical chunks where the html will display correctly in the browser, and each time the more button is clicked, the remaining content is displayed, or the next chunk is displayed.